# Отправка двух форм одной кнопкой

Tags: javascript, php, html

Может кто подскажет как отправить две формы одной кнопкой Submit. Надо, чтобы после заполнения формы пользователем, они отправлялись на почту и перенаправляло на страницу оплаты робокасса. Я пробовал, но дальше почты ничего не получается. Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: Можете попробовать сделать это через js. Вот пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button